# Uncheck all checkboxes with button click

Tags: java, android, eclipse, button, checkbox

I'm currently making an app with a lot of checkboxes (39 to be spcific) and I want to implement a button that will uncheck them when it's clicked. I haven't done much with buttons (I only used them to start a new activity so far) so I'm still not completely sure how they work. After doing some research this is what I came up with. Even though I have 39 checkboxes I will only paste a few in this code to keep it short.

```
CheckBox cb1 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox2);
CheckBox cb2 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox3);
CheckBox cb3 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox4);
public void onClick (View v){
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.button1:
            cb1.setChecked(false);
            cb2.setChecked(false);
            cb3.setChecked(false);
    }
}
```

LogCat:

```
06-12 06:45:09.922: E/AndroidRuntime(6623): FATAL EXCEPTION: main 
06-12 06:45:09.922: E/AndroidRuntime(6623): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.gw2legendary/com.example.gw2legendary.Bifrost}: java.lang.NullPointerException 
06-12 06:45:09.922: E/AndroidRuntime(6623): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

The problem is that my activity crashes as soon as I try to open it with I add this code to it. The activity starts fine if I remove this code from it.

Comment: where do you have all the 39 check boxes in a listview?

Comment: 06-12 06:45:09.922: E/AndroidRuntime(6623): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-12 06:45:09.922: E/AndroidRuntime(6623): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.gw2legendary/com.example.gw2legendary.Bifrost}: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-12 06:45:09.922: E/AndroidRuntime(6623): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: It actually crashes when I try to open the activity that contains this button.

Comment: Please post whole logcat in question. You can edit it.

Comment: Then post the code when you start the new activity. Because that is where the problem occurs

Comment: I have them in a Scroll View. The activity started completely fine until I added this code for unchecking boxes so the problem must be here.

Comment: Is this activity implementing onClickListener?

Comment: No, but it is implementing an OnCheckedChangeListener

Comment: Implement onClickListener. Otherwise don't write onClick the way you have written.

Comment: @AReader: I'm pretty sure he declared the onClick on the XML

Comment: @dmon I don't know, I am not sure he did so. The method name is onClick. And he's checking using switch case about checked button's id too. He might have to check that once, I think.

Comment: I did implement the onClick listener now and did what "dmon" told me to do and it works. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Glad we could help. Happy coding :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the reason your code is failing: you declared your  CheckBox variables as class fields, and they are initialized when the Activity starts, so the `findViewById()` returns null for all of them.

A quick fix: move all of those Checkbox declarations inside of your onClick method. Though it seems you might be using them somewhere else before the click.

A better potential solution: instead of trying to reference all of your 39 (!) checkboxes, it might be better to just get a reference to the *container* and iterate through all of the children, check if they are checkboxes and uncheck them if they are.

I will say that 39 checkboxes seems a bit ridiculous though.

Comment: I moved those declarations inside the method and it worked perfectly! Thank you. Could you just please give me a small explanation in the "containter" and "children"? I'm new to android programming so those expressions are new to me.

Comment: It's hard to help you without your XML (so I know what the container is). The "container" is just the parent ViewGroup (e.g a LinearLayout) that has all of these checkboxes. You can iterate through a ViewGroup's children (using the [getChildAt and getChildCount](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#getChildAt(int)) methods. Then you can use `instanceof` to make sure that the `childAt(x)` is actually a Checkbox.

Comment: Thanks, I will do some more research on this when I get home from school :) But I can tell right now that thoes checkboxer are inside Relative Layout which is inside Scroll View.